# When launching react / express application, an extra port is launched

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

When i run my react / express application it is first launched on the port and only after 3000 (client) and 8000 (server) ports are launched. This is what it outputs to the console
==========> [1] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.0.102/

```
[0] Express server is running on port 8000
[1] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.0.102/        
[1] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
[1] i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\allek\OneDrive\Desktop\iron_react\ironcage\iron_react\client\public
[1] i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1]
[1] You can now view client in the browser.
[1]
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000
[1]   On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.102:3000
[1]
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

Here is my package.json setting for start

```
 "scripts": {
    "client-install": "cd client && yarn install",
    "backend": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "start": "concurrently \"yarn run server\" \"yarn run client\""
  }
```

and here is my webpack config overrides settings (but this does not play a role in the problem)

```
  const {
  override,
  fixBabelImports,
  overrideDevServer,
  addLessLoader
} = require('customize-cra');

const devServerConfig = () => config => {
  return {
    ...config,
    open: true,
    overlay: true,
    compress: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000/',
        secure: false
      },
    },
  }
}


module.exports = {
  webpack: override(
    fixBabelImports('import', {
      libraryName: 'antd',
      libraryDirectory: 'es',
      style: true,
    }),
    addLessLoader({
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      modifyVars: {},
    }),
  ),
  devServer: overrideDevServer(
    devServerConfig()
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It happen because create-react app open in new window my project when it get ready, but in config-override I open it too but without waiting, so I just remove open in new window in config override